# problem during data update in php ajax

Tags: php, ajax

ajax code-

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","voting.php?qid="+qid+"&amp;uid="+uid+"&amp;type="+type,true);
```

html-

```
<td ><img src="images/up.jpeg" style="border:none;" title="Like" 
                onclick="doVote('<?php echo $q_id; ?>','<?php echo $_SESSION['UserId']; ?>','up')"></td>
```

**problem:** `qid` is getting passed to voting.php page but `uid` and `type` are not.Why?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","voting.php?qid="+qid+"&uid="+uid+"&type="+type,true);
```

?